# combination vs permutation. Order Vs no order matters

Tags: combinatorics

Only one row of 4 seats remained in the bus. How many different ways can six friends be accommodated if by chivalry the two girls in the group cannot remain standing? My answer is $\binom{4}{2}4!$, is that right if we assume order matters?

Comment: Yes, it is: $\binom42$ ways to choose $2$ men to stand, and $4!$ ways to order the $4$ who are seated.